# Rare case seen when Aerospike give older value but not updated value

Tags: java, aerospike

In distributed environment daily 2 million request comes then first we try to read the data and then update the data in aerospike on the basis of key. But in rare case some time when we are reading the data then it read the older value.

The average time between the updating the value and reading that value is 10sec in which these issue come. So can someone please help me to figure out where is the problem either it is in setup or in code.

Comment: Are you using strong-consistency? https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#strong-consistency

Comment: If not using strong-consistency, I could see different situations when this could happen when running with the default client policies. Something as simple as a write failing to replicate (would return an error on the write) and a client policy retrying against a replica copy by default (where the replica copy has the older value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAP theorem matters if there are node failures or nodes going in and out of the cluster.  Reading stale reads, even in AP mode, in a stable cluster, does not add up. Secondly, Aerospike is not an eventually consistent design - it is immediately consistent in a stable cluster because it is not a consensus based design. So either the cluster is unstable due to network issues and nodes are going in and out or some combination of network events is causing this or there is some issue with the code. Hard to diagnose just by a statement of end observation. So 1) Is the cluster stable thru these events? 2) What is the Aerospike version? Edition - Community or Enterprise? 3) Cluster size? 4) Namespace configuration? 5) Replication factor?  6) Code snippet / data model / what exactly are you doing in code?  If the write update fails, how are you handling it in code?

Answer (score 2):

What version of Aerospike are you using? Also, you can achieve only 2 aspects at a time of [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). My guess is, currently, your aerospike settings are for [Eventual Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency)

As of version 4.0, you have the option to choose AP (Available and Partition Tolerant) as well as CP (Consistent and Partition Tolerant) mode.

More details on aerospike consistency [here](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/consistency.html).

Comment: we are using aerospike version 3.4

Comment: Ver 3.4 ... lots of improvements, changes since then. Even Aerospike does not support it anymore. I assume you are on Community Edition? Consider upgrading. You have to go through a jump version - 3.13 first, to go to latest. Follow release notes here and plan it out! https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html

Comment: Another vote to upgrade, while this scenario is still possible in latest versions of AP, it is far less likely. There were a few design flaws with the old distributed system code prior to 3.13 which could leave partitions believing they are in sync when they aren't which could easily manifest as this symptom. 3.4 is very old and our release processes have drastically improved since it was released, I highly recommend upgrading.